# Toggle a "hide table" button with "search" button

Tags: javascript, toggle

I want to toggle a "hide table" button with a "search" button so that it only appears when the searched table appears and disappears. Both the functions initiated by `onClick` work, it's just the toggle. Any help would be great! thanks.

```
<input name="Search_Country" id="Search_Country" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="searched_country_table()"/>
<input id="Hide" value="Hide Table" type="button" onclick="hide_table()">
<div id="search_table"></div>
```

Comment: show the functions' codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a framework, for example jquery

```js
$( function(){
  
  $("#search_table").hide();
  $("#idhide").hide();
  
  $("#idshow").click( function(event){
    $("#search_table").show("slow");
    $("#idshow").hide();
    $("#idhide").show();
  });
  
  $("#idhide").click( function(event){
    $("#search_table").hide("slow");
    $("#idhide").hide();
    $("#idshow").show();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="Search_Country" id="Search_Country"  type="text">
    <input id="idshow"type="button" value="Search"/>
     <input id="idhide" value="Hide Table" type="button" />
      <div id="search_table">The Table</div>
```

Comment: how would I get the 'hide table' button to toggle with the search button?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jQuery from just hiding and showing an element.

```js
window.onload = function () {               //Check the page is loaded

  function id(a){return document.getElementById(a)}

  id('search_table').style.display = 'none'; //Hide Table
  id('Hide').style.display = 'none';         //Hide Hide button
  
  id('Search').onclick = function () {       //When the search button is clicked
    id('search_table').style.display = 'block';//Show table
    this.style.display = 'none';               //Hide Search
    id('Hide').style.display = 'inline';       //Show hide button
  };
  
  id('Hide').onclick = function () {          //Hide button clicked
    id('search_table').style.display = 'none';//Hide table
    this.style.display = 'none';              //Hide Hide button
    id('Search').style.display = 'inline';    //Show search button
  };
  
};
```

```html
<input name="Search_Country" id="Search_Country" type="text">
<input id="Search" type="button" value="Search" onclick="searched_country_table()" />
<input id="Hide" value="Hide Table" type="button" onclick="hide_table()">
<div id="search_table">Table</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would fit your needs well - Hide hide-button initially, show when search is clicked and hide both results and hide-button when hide-button clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#searchTable").hide();
  $("#buttonHide").hide();
  
  $("#buttonShow").on("click", function(event){
    $("#searchTable").show();
    $("#tableContent").append($("#searchCountry").val() + "<br />");
    $("#buttonHide").show();
  });
  
  $("#buttonHide").click( function(event){
    $("#searchTable").toggle();
    $("#buttonHide").toggle();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Toggle Example</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <input name="Search_Country" id="searchCountry" type="text">
  <input id="buttonShow" type="button" value="Search"/>
  <input id="buttonHide" value="Hide Table" type="button" />
  <div id="searchTable">The Table
    <div id="tableContent">
      
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```